# Video is not playing in default player of android device

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, android-videoview

I am using ffmpeg command for padding a video. After padding video, video is becoming bigger than the screen size of android device. Because of the bigger size video is not playing in videoview.  It can be played by scaling padded video to screen size of the device. But i don't want to scale the video.Finally my question is "How to play a video of bigger size than the screen size in android in video view"?

Answer (score 0):

The stock video player is limited, and its limits depend on the device hardware and firmware. This means that the same video may be playable on a different device, or after flashing an upgrade.

Often, Android devices can play videos "bigger" than the screen, but sometimes the problem is that the size is not one of the standard sizes (such as 720p or 1080p), or use main profile vs. baseline profile (see [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451180/android-videoview-cannot-play-video-mp4)), or some other incompatibility. See also *[Android Video View not playing MP4 file on some devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151685/android-video-view-not-playing-mp4-file-on-some-devices)*.

Comment: Alex Cohn thanks for your reply. I did not get you "use main profile vs. basic profile".

Comment: See e.g. http://superuser.com/questions/489087/what-are-the-differences-between-h-264-profiles