# Android httpresponse download png from index.php

Tags: php, android

I've the following problem.

1. I'll send a httpost to a index.php file
2. My index.php file returns header('image/png') and off course the file
3. Then my code will download the response to a file on the device SD Card
4. It is downloaded and on the device SD card with the right size (this image in the example is, 34Mb)

But when it has been downloaded, I can not open the file on the device.
Does someone know what the problem can be?

```js
String file = "18228";

HttpClient httpclient=new MyHttpClient(mContext); // MyHttpCient handles https
HttpPost httppost= new HttpPost("https://example.com/json/index.php"); // make sure the url is correct.

HttpResponse response=httpclient.execute(httppost);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("requestFile",file));

StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
File SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File fileDownload = new File(SDCardRoot + "/MyFiles" , "General-information-Example.jpg");

InputStream input = null;
OutputStream output = null;
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

try {
  System.out.println("Downloading file...");
  input = response.getEntity().getContent();
  output = new FileOutputStream(fileDownload);
  for (int length; (length = input.read(buffer)) > 0;) {
    output.write(buffer, 0, length);
  }
  System.out.println("File successfully downloaded!");
} finally {
  if (output != null) try { output.close(); } catch (IOException logOrIgnore) {}
  if (input != null) try { input.close(); } catch (IOException logOrIgnore) {}
}
```

```js
<?php

header('Content-Type: '.$loadFile['header'].''); 
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($loadFile['file']));
header('Pragma: public');
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
header('Content-Disposition: filename="' . basename($loadFile['file']));
header('X-Pad: avoid browser bug');
readfile($loadFile['file']);
exit;

?>
```

```js
04-12 12:52:35.080    4822-4999/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley I/System.out﹕ Downloading file...
04-12 12:52:47.410    4822-4999/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley I/System.out﹕ File successfully downloaded!
04-12 12:53:08.370    4822-4822/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Flushing caches (mode 0)
04-12 12:53:08.400    4822-4822/info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Flushing caches (mode 1)
```

Comment: The same problem accords with Pdf, Mp4 and other files when I download it to the device. I can not open the files.

Comment: When I change the post to a get with the direct image link then it will download. So I think the problem lays with the headers of the php file. HttpClient httpclient = new MyHttpClient(mContext);
            HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet("http://example.com/General-information-Example.jpg");

Comment: I checked same problem accords with files > 25MB. When I do a get on a file bigger then 25MB it also not opens :(.

Comment: The images will not load because they are CMYK. So by solving (server side) image convert to RGB that should fix the first file type problem will not open.

Comment: The images are working now.

Comment: The Pdf is working. Problem was the header('Accept-Ranges: bytes'); header in Php file.

Comment: Video's are working. Problem is some codecs are not playing. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151685/android-video-view-not-playing-mp4-file-on-some-devices

Answer (score 0):

put  `output.flush();` before closing your output

your finally statement should be something like this : `if (output != null) try {output.flush(); output.close(); } catch (IOException logOrIgnore) {}`

Comment: Thank you, but this not solved the problem. It still downloads but I can not open the image.

Answer (score 0):

1. Images where CMYK, should be RGB
2. Video's are not always working, depending on codec